# WPF - Why Listbox items do not fill uniformgrid

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemspaneltemplate

I have a listbox with the ItemsPanelTemplate set to UniformGrid with rows= 6 and cols= 7.

I want the listbox items to fill their space.

I am using a datatemplete defined in a dictionary.

The outer control of my template is a Border with HorizontalAlignment=Stretch
and VerticalAlignent=Strectch but the templates do not fill the listbox items space?

Any ideas?
Malcolm

Comment: Can you provide a sample XAML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Items do not fill wpf listbox using datatemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402274/items-do-not-fill-wpf-listbox-using-datatemplate)

Answer (score 11):

The answer to this to set HorizontalContentAligment and VerticalContentAlignment to Stretch on the LISTBOX not the datatemplate.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: Added additional information, and replied to question.

An interesting way to make `ListBoxItems` be uniform with other items is to the `Grid`s shared scope feature in your `DataTemplate`

Example:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Content"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
        </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now all the `TextBlocks` will be the same size in your layout. The child item should fill all available space if no specific width/height are set.

Alternatively you can set the Width and Height of the control to stretched, however I think using the Grid.SharedScopeSize is a more elegant way to achieving the same effect.