# How can I make a ListBoxItem stretch Vertically

Tags: wpf, listbox, autosize

I would like to make a `ListBox` function like a `Grid`. Each time a new item is added it should look like a a new `GridRow` was added (with a height of star). So if there are two items they will each take up half of the available space. At some point the `Grid` row will be smaller than the items `MinHeight` at which point the `Grid` will expand and a containing ScrollViewer can kick in.

You will see this behavior with a grid inside a `ScrollViewer`. However, I need to get this working with a `ListBox` so I can just set the `ItemsSource`, create a `DataTemplate` and move on.

The problem with the default `ListBox` `ItemsPanel` is that it will not let my first item expand to fill all the available space.

UPDATE:
Here's the code to get it working:

```
<ListBox VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO post has some pretty good information that seems relevant to your post
[WPF - Why Listbox items do not fill uniformgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399713/wpf-why-listbox-items-do-not-fill-uniformgrid)

Comment: Thanks that helped, I don't use the uniform grid much so I never thought of it.